# can we return xml document to client side application instead of saving it at particular destination

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have a webservice webmethod which saves the xml output to destination

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XmlDocument GetList(
  string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
{      
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = CreateXML( keyword1,streetname,lat,lng,radius);

  //save file to application folder which will be refferd by client application
  xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Block3.xml"));
  return xmldoc;       
}
```

I am trying to refer from client side using the following code in searchurl

```
function searchLocationsNear() {
  var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;             
  var searchUrl ="http://localhost:2385/block/Block3.xml"; //reference for xml file stored in application folder

  GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a simple example of how you might use jQuery to call the server side `WebMethod` from the client side. This code assumes that you are hosting the `searchLocationNear(...)` method in `WebService1.asmx`

```
  function searchLocationNear() {
    // Get the radius using jQuery
    var radius = $("#radiusSelect").val();

    // Make Ajax call using jQuery
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "keyword1=&streetname=&lat=&lng=&radius=" + radius,
      url: "WebService1.asmx/GetList",
      success: function (response) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(response.xml);
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here `$.ajax` is used to make a call to the `GetList` web method, and the XML is extracted from the response. This works find if you are returning an XmlDocument on the server side as in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,can i pass json constructed data to webservice and get back xml as response ,in that case should my datatype be xml or json

Comment: @mahesh, yes you can pass JSON data and get back the XML, just add `datatype: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` to the above ajax call and format the data using JSON format like this `data: "{keyword1: '', streetname: '', lat: '', lng: '', radius:" + radius + "}"`

Comment: [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XmlDocument GetList(
  string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
{      
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = CreateXML( keyword1,streetname,lat,lng,radius);
return xmldoc;
 
}

Comment: @mahesh, is there a specific error you are getting? The above looks fine, did you add `[ScriptService]` to the actual service class?

Comment: Ya i have added using System.Web.Script.Services; Its working fine now thank you very much.

Comment: Please let me know if their are any good articles which uses jquery in html page on client side and asp.net webservices on serverside

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to:

1. [Call the web method from javascript](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx)
2. [Use XmlDocument object in javascript](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/convert-xml-document-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I wll be using html and jquery on my clientside